# Profile2 and profile fields by user role

Tags: users

I have some profile fields created with the [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module, which creates a main profile containing all the fields.
In the user/%/edit/main path, I see a new tab which displays a form to edit profile fields.

I have also three user roles, ( e.g. role A, B and C), and I want to remove that menu path for the role C. Alternatively, I want to restrict the access to those profile fields by user role.

Can I use the module [Profile2 Privacy](http://drupal.org/project/profile2_privacy) to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done with `hook_process_page()` and removed the variable `secondary_local_tasks` before rendering to the template if the logged-in user is role C. No need additional module.

```
function mymodule_process_page(&$vars, $hooks){
    global $user;
    if(array_key_exists(6, $user->roles) && arg(0) == 'user' && arg(2) == 'edit'){
        # if user role C, hide profile tab
        $vars['tabs']['#secondary'] = array();
        if(isset($vars['secondary_local_tasks'])){
            $vars['secondary_local_tasks'] = array();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried this from `hook_preprocess_page()`, but it did not work on the sky theme.
Related question is here : [Menu local tasks and hook preprocess](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21134/menu-local-tasks-and-hook-preprocess)

Answer (score 1):

To restrict access to the fileds, I used the module [Field permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) to set each field individually for each user role.

Comment: I have 5 profile fields in the main profile which is tab-grouped in user edit page. After I restricted access to those 5 fields, will the whole tab be thrown away from the user edit page ?

Comment: Yes, as far as i know is the tab gone then ... but not 100% sure. Just try it out.

Comment: Unfortunately, the tab was not gone although all fields were disappeared. The form was alone with a save button. I tried to hide the secondary menu local task from `hook_preprocess_menu_local_tasks()`. It works on seven theme, but not in sky theme.