# Menu local tasks and hook preprocess

Tags: routes, hooks, theming

I just want to remove a secondary menu local task from a preprocess function such as

```
function mymodule_preprocess_menu_local_tasks(&$vars, $hooks) { 
    $vars['secondary'] = '';
}
```

I'm using D7, **sky** theme for front-end and **seven** theme for admin.
The above code works in **seven** but not in **sky**.

The sky theme page.tpl.php has a variable `$secondary_local_tasks` which I might be able to remove from `hook_preprocess_page()`. I also tried this :

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hooks) { 
    $vars['secondary_local_tasks'] = '';
    unset($vars['tabs']['#secondary']);
}
```

My hook is invoked correctly, but the secondary local task is still rendered to the template. Where local tasks are prepared to be rendered after my hook ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've done with `hook_process_page()` and removed the variable `secondary_local_tasks` upon logged-in user role before rendering to the template.

```
function mymodule_process_page(&$vars, $hooks){
    global $user;
    if(array_key_exists(6, $user->roles) && arg(0) == 'user' && arg(2) == 'edit'){
        $vars['tabs']['#secondary'] = array();
        if(isset($vars['secondary_local_tasks'])){
            $vars['secondary_local_tasks'] = array();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried this from `hook_preprocess_page()`, but it did not work on the sky theme.
Related question is here : [Profile2 and profile fields by user role](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21030/profile2-and-profile-fields-by-user-role/21154#21154)

Answer (score 1):

Or use: [hook_menu_local_tasks_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/7)()

Comment: This is the really right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [hook_menu_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to remove any menu entry. This would be completely indipendent of the theme.

Just implement `hook_menu_alter` in a custom module and look at the given menu items with a dubugger or dpm(). Then do something like this:

```
unset($items['menu/item/to/delete'];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I will remove the tab dynamically upon logged-in user role. `hook_menu_alter` does not run on every page load.