# How to place the page title and local tasks tab in a Panels region?

Tags: panels

Is it possible to move the displayed page title (h1) and the local task tabs below it (the 'view' and 'edit' node tabs) to a region? Panels displays these by default for node/% page overrides.

I can add the local task tabs to a region of my choice, but I can't see how to remove the default node local task tabs.

And while I can set the page variant to 'no title', that's not really what I need, I want to define the region where it should be shown. I can add the 'Page title' from the page elements Panels content in the region I want, but it is empty when I set the page variant to 'no title'. I could add the title field and wrap it in h1 tags myself so I can use the 'no title' setting, or hide the first occurrence of the h1 with css and use the extra 'Page title' element, but it seems there should be a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just wanting to do that for a single variant, you may need a combination of panels configuration, e.g adding local tasks and page title to region as well as either `hook_preprocess_page` or perhaps `hook_ctools_render_alter` to remove the page title and tabs from default output based on path or other criteria.

For example:

template.php

```
/**
 * hook_preprocess_page
 * Alter variables for the page template
 */
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars){
  // If on a node page
  if ($node = menu_get_object('node')) {
    // Remove page title and menu tabs for this node type
    // as they're output in the panel variant instead
    if ($node->type == 'my_type') {
      $vars['title'] = FALSE;
      $vars['tabs'] = FALSE;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on the second part, how to remove page title and tabs for a particular variant?

Comment: @arjan example preprocess_page snippet to remove title and tabs from default page.tpl output added.

Comment: I had to use `$vars['primary_local_tasks'] = FALSE;`, although `['tabs']` was also present. [Related issue](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/21134/3939).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove or otherwise affect the page-level elements, such as menus, that's out of scope for Panels, as it only deals with the content/entity being displayed.

[Panels everywhere](http://drupal.org/project/panels_everywhere) however does for the page template what panels does for the node template and can be applied selectively to pages with selection rules just like other variants.

Comment: Looks like I should look into using Panels everywhere for future projects (converting the current site to it may be too much work).

Comment: No need to convert the whole site in one go. Set a restrictive selection rule, and PE will fall back to the page template for everything that doesn't fit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Title](http://drupal.org/project/title) module? It transforms the Title property to a full Field API field with all the benefits coming with that. As a bonus it will also be fully translatable too.

Comment: But adding the title to a region isn't the problem, preventing the default page title + local tasks tabs from always rendering is. Title module wouldn't affect that would it?